# how to avoid gson tojson recursion

Tags: java, json, gson

I have very simple class:

```
MyObject:
 - String index;
 - MyObject parent;
 - List<MyObject> childs;
```

I want to print stored information into json. I use toJson function of Gson library. But due to every child has a link to parent object I face with infinite loop recursion. Is there a way to define that gson shall print only parent index for every child instead of dumping full information?

Comment: I resolve the issue using `transient` to parent and add `String parentIndex`. Is it possible to answer the question without introduction of additional field parentIndex?

Answer (score 6):

you need to use the [@Expose](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) annotation.

```
public class MyObject{

    @Expose
    String index;

    MyObject parent;

    @Expose
    List<MyObject> children;

}
```

Then generate the json using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
jsonString = gson.toJson(data);
```

Edit:
you can do a dfs parse when you convert it back to the object. Just make a method like:

```
public void setParents(MyObj patent){ 
    this.parent=parent; 
    for(MyObj o:children){
        o.setParent(this); 
    }
}
```

and call it for the root object.

Comment: But I need an index of a parent for each object in jsonString.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today and found another solution that I'd like to share :

You can declare an attribute as `transient` and it won't be serialized or deserialized :

```
public class MyObject{
  String index;
  transient MyObject parent;
  List<MyObject> children;
}
```

---

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(obj); // parent will not show up
```